# The simple but correct way to have a bash script send output to systemd journal?

Tags: bash, shell-script, systemd, logs, systemd-journald

I have simply been sticking something like this at the top of my bash scripts. This still works with systemd. (I have used it for a long time and I don't fully understand it. It just works, so I use it.)

```
exec 5> >(logger -t $0)
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$LINENO: '
set -x
```

Even with systemd, the above commands give the expected output in journalctl. However, it seems that maybe I should be using something like this instead.

```
systemd-cat -t $0
```

How should I alter my current logging commands under systemd?

(I'm looking for the same kind of simple-minded solution where I can paste a few lines and get some output in the journal.)

Comment: Clever snippet, actually.  You should dig in to understand what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. You have motivated me to dig into it. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would stick with `logger`: it works with any standards-compliant logging system, including systemd’s journal as you’ve discovered. Using `systemd-cat` directly would only make your scripts systemd-specific, without adding anything; in fact, modern [`logger`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) is much more flexible, and provides better support for systemd-specific features than [`systemd-cat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd-cat.1.html) itself.

Comment: POSIX specifications for `logger` say that its standard input is "not used."  Implementations seem to depart from that for better usability.

Comment: @Wildcard yes, POSIX `logger` is very basic, since we’re comparing with systemd here I just went with the `util-linux` variant.

Comment: @Wildcard you can always use logger with xargs.